# Retrieve and access each line separately from text file using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a text file, urls.txt, containing a few different urls for websites:

```
http://google.com
http://postgresql.com
http://dfsghlkjdflkjdfhkl.com
https://nodejs.org/api/console.html
```

I'm trying to get each line separately using lineReader so I can ultimately pass each url to a handler to read that html

Here is my app.js:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const lineReader = require('line-reader')

lineReader.eachLine('urls.txt', function(line){
    console.log(line)
})
```

The above will print each line to the terminal. I've tried splitting the lines with something like

```
let arr = line.split(/\r?\n/);
```

...and then accessing at an index, but all I can seem to retrieve is a single text character from each line using that method. I feel like the solution is going to be really obvious, but I've been surfing for the last 2 hours trying to figure this one out!

Comment: Push every line into an array, then you will have an index for every line.

Comment: Thanks, @Teemu. I knew there was an easy solution but stuck in a classic case of overthinking.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to solve my issue. Hopefully this will help someone in the future not get stuck in their own head about it.

```
let arr = fs.readFileSync('urls.txt').toString().split("\n");
for(i in arr) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Just a heads-up. If you need just the array's values, might be better to use `for-of` loop instead of `for-in`. Something like `for (const line of arr) { console.log(line); }`